# Python multiprocessing for large dataset evaluation with sharing da

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've a script that I try to transform in multiprocess because I'll have a large amount of data to proceed. I tried to put together some code that I found during my research but I can't make it works with multiprocess.

The idea of the script is define like this:

- Generate all combinations and filter it
- Slice the combinations in chunk of x (1000) combos to be evaluated
- Create multiple process for evaluate 1 sliced part

  - if the sum of value of the combination is greater than the current maximum, change the maximum for this value and it must be share for other process as the new maximum

There's the script:

```
import itertools
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from math import factorial
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Pool, Manager, Lock

def total_combo(n, r):
    return factorial(n) // factorial(r) // factorial(n-r)

def iterator_slice(iterator, length):
    iterator = iter(iterator)
    while True:
        res = tuple(itertools.islice(iterator, length))
        if not res:
            break
        yield res


def evaluate_combination(combinations, best_combination, max_value, lock):
           
    for combination in combinations:
        #total_index = sum(people['index'] for people in combination)
        total_value = sum(people['value'] for people in combination)
        
        # Check if the combination meets the constraints
        if total_value > max_value.value:
            with lock:
                best_combination = list(combination)
                max_value.value = total_value

def generate_filtered_combinations(players,r):
    return itertools.filterfalse(lambda y: sum(x['index'] for x in y) > 30, itertools.combinations(players, r))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    start = timer()
    
    # Example usage
    players = [
        {"people":"John Doe1","index":8,"value":15},
        {"people":"John Doe2","index":7,"value":28},
        {"people":"John Doe3","index":6,"value":13},
        {"people":"John Doe4","index":7,"value":11},
        {"people":"John Smith1","index":7,"value":11},
        {"people":"John Smith2","index":6,"value":9},
        {"people":"John Smith3","index":6,"value":10},
        # .... just some data for example
    ];
    
    manager = Manager()
        
    max_value = manager.Value('i', 0)
    best_combination = manager.list()
    lock = Lock()
       
    for r in range(6,8):
        print(r, total_combo(len(players),r)) # max possible items in the combination for r with players
        combos = generate_filtered_combinations(players,r) # generate all combinations filtered
              
        pool = Pool(4)  # lets use 4 workers
        cursor_iterator = iterator_slice(combos, 1000)  # slice it
        queue = []  # a queue for our current worker async results, a deque would be faster
        
        while cursor_iterator or queue:  # while we have anything to do...
            try:
                # add our next slice to the pool:
                queue.append(pool.apply_async(evaluate_combination, [next(cursor_iterator), best_combination, max_value, lock]))
            except (StopIteration, TypeError):  # no more data, clear out the slice iterator
                cursor_iterator = None
            # wait for a free worker or until all remaining finish
            while queue and (len(queue) >= pool._processes or not cursor_iterator):
                process = queue.pop(0)  # grab a process response from the top
                if not process.ready():  # a sub-process has not finished execution
                    queue.append(process)  # add it back to the queue
                else:
                    # you can use process.get() to get the result if needed
                    pass
        pool.close()
        
    # Print the best combination
    for people in best_combination:
        print(people['people'],people['index'])
    
    print(max_value.value)

    end = timer()
    print(end - start)
```

For now, the `max_value` is never updated (neither `best_combination`). The `with lock:` seems to not working.

Thanks in advance for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confess to having had some difficulty in following your logic, but I do see a few issues:

1. With your `players` test data and your definition of `generate_filtered_combinations(players,r)` with argument *r* taking on values 6 and 7, there is no way for this function to return any combinations that match its criterion. This is why `max_value`, for instance, never gets updated. So I am changing *r* to take on values 2 and 3. Likewise, I am slicing up the combinations in chunks of size 3.
2. Your serializing computations with `lock` variable needs "adjustment", i.e. the locking should be done sooner.
3. Your statement `best_combination = list(combination)` does not update the managed list with the elements of combination; it is replacing what was a proxy to a managed list with a reference to a local list. Unfortunately, the proxy does not support the `list.clear()` method. So I had to resort to popping off all the elements one by one until the list was empty and then I called the `extend` method to add the new combination to the list. You might consider creating your own version of a managed list that does support the `clear` method.
4. Since your are creating a separate `Lock` instance, there is no need to create a lock for the `max_value` shared variable, so I have added `*lock=False* for its initialization.

Where I was most confused was the use of *queue* and the loop that uses it and why you are looping on `r`. I have greatly simplified the code (perhaps erroneously) by eliminating this `queue` and using method `pool.imap_unordered`. I also no longer pass variables `best_combination`, `max_value`, and `lock` on every invocation of `evaluate_combination`. Instead, each pool process is initialized once with global variables of these values.

```py
import itertools
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from math import factorial
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Pool, Manager, Lock

def total_combo(n, r):
    return factorial(n) // factorial(r) // factorial(n-r)

def iterator_slice(iterator, length):
    iterator = iter(iterator)
    while True:
        res = tuple(itertools.islice(iterator, length))
        if not res:
            break
        yield res

def init_pool_processes(*args):
    global best_combination, max_value, lock

    best_combination, max_value, lock = args

def evaluate_combination(combinations):

    for combination in combinations:
        #total_index = sum(people['index'] for people in combination)
        total_value = sum(people['value'] for people in combination)

        with lock: # Booboo: locking moved
            # Check if the combination meets the constraints
            if total_value > max_value.value:
                #best_combination = list(combination) # Booboo
                while len(best_combination):
                    best_combination.pop()
                best_combination.extend(combination)
                max_value.value = total_value

def generate_filtered_combinations(players,r):
    return itertools.filterfalse(lambda y: sum(x['index'] for x in y) > 30, itertools.combinations(players, r))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    start = timer()

    # Example usage
    players = [
        {"people":"John Doe1","index":8,"value":15},
        {"people":"John Doe2","index":7,"value":28},
        {"people":"John Doe3","index":6,"value":13},
        {"people":"John Doe4","index":7,"value":11},
        {"people":"John Smith1","index":7,"value":11},
        {"people":"John Smith2","index":6,"value":9},
        {"people":"John Smith3","index":6,"value":10},
        # .... just some data for example
    ];

    manager = Manager()

    max_value = manager.Value('i', 0, lock=False) # Booboo - don't need lock here
    best_combination = manager.list()
    lock = Lock()

    pool = Pool(4, initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(best_combination, max_value, lock))  # lets use POOL_SIZE workers
    for r in range(2, 4):
        print(r, total_combo(len(players),r)) # max possible items in the combination for r with players
        combos = generate_filtered_combinations(players,r) # generate all combinations filtered

        cursor_iterator = iterator_slice(combos, 3)  # slice it
        it = pool.imap_unordered(evaluate_combination, cursor_iterator)
        # If return values from evaluate_combination were required,
        # you would un-comment out the next two lines:
        #for result in it:
        #    print(result)

    # Wait for tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Print the best combination
    for people in best_combination:
        print(people['people'],people['index'])

    print(max_value.value)

    end = timer()
    print(end - start)
```

Prints:

```None
2 21
3 35
John Doe1 8
John Doe2 7
John Doe3 6
56
0.30639590000000005
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. It works with your adjustment but take way more times than sequential : with a player list of 34 and range(2,5) take 7,7 sec with multiprocessing while take 0.12 seconds in sequential.

There's additionnal info about your points :
1. My bad. You're right. I shrunk my sample dataset for not having a long question but forgot to adjust the r value.

Comment: That just means that certain tasks are not suitable for multiprocessing. There is overhead in creating processes and moving data to and from one process's address space to another. Therefore, what is gained by running calculations in parallel must exceed the additional multiprocessing overhead. I could have told you that your `evaluate_combination` is far too trivial in its CPU requirements to compensate for this overhead. For all I know this function was a simplification of the actual function, which might benefit from multiprocessing. **I believe I did provide an *acceptable* answer.**

Comment: I should add that using a *managed* list, `best_combination`, is at best a "slow performer" but especially in this case where we are making so many calls on it just to empty it. Each call required is essentially the equivalent of a remote procedure call. That means your arguments are serialized and sent via a socket or pipe to another process for action on the *real* underlying queue.

Comment: Your answer help me a lot to understand and make it work. I understand that my function is not enough CPU needed vs the MP overhead.

Comment: I've try without updating the list `best_combination`. I gain some time but still far of sequential to thinking that MP can help me in this case.

Comment: One further thing: All these calls to the managed list are being serialized because of the locking that is required so that we have consistent results. This really is killing any parallelism. A solution that somehow implements a list in *shared memory* (I have thoughts on this), would go a long way to improving performance, but would probably still be less efficient than sequential processing.

Comment: Our comments crossed. So: when you remove the calls on the managed list (the entire block beginning with `with lock:`. what was the total time?

Comment: Without the `with lock` it takes 1.47 sec.
Removing the best_combination update I gain only 0.2 sec.